# Inequality operator not allowed for this type: Object

Tags: apex, data-types, typecast

When trying to compare any two arbitrary `Object` values to determine order, I get the following error.

> Inequality operator not allowed for this type: Object

Below is sample code that will not compile.

```
public class SummaryHelper {

    /**
    * The implementation of compare returns the following values:
    *
    * - 0 if lhs and rhs are equal
    * - > 0 if lhs is greater than rhs
    * - < 0 if lhs is less than rhs
    *
    * @param lhs Left-hand side value in the comparison expression.
    * 
    * @param rhs Right-hand side value in the comparison expression.
    * 
    * @return The equivalent of `lhs.compareTo(rhs)` if both lhs and rhs
    *         were `Comparable` objects.
    * 
    * @see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm
    */
    public static Integer compare(Object lhs, Object rhs) {
        return lhs == rhs
            ? 0
            : (lhs > rhs ? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```

How can I dynamically compare two objects without having to know the type of the object beforehand? In my situation, I'd love to use the same function for comparing `Date`, `Datetime`, `Decimal` and `String` values.

Answer (score 2):

It requires a pile of `instanceOf` and casts:

```
public static Integer compare(Object lhs, Object rhs) {
    if (lhs instanceOf Date && rhs instanceOf Date) {
        Date l = (Date) lhs;
        Date r = (Date) rhs;
        if (l < r) return -1;
        else if (r > l) return 1;
        else return 0;
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Painful to write but pretty mechanical.

Check for `Date` before `DateTime` - see [Instanceof for Apex Date and DateTime](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/instanceof-for-apex-date-and-datetime/). And best start with `null` guards.